# Sub column in itext

Tags: java, itext

[Like this](http://www.dropbox.com/s/txw78c84a3u0b4y/Untitled.png)
I got 8 columns in the table. But the 4th column has likely 12-sub columns under it. Can anyone suggest how to create a table like that in itext. To be more specific, i need to add 12 more sub columns under the 4th column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is wrong. You want a table with 19 columns of which one and only one cell has a colspan of 12. The solution to your question is as simple as using `setColspan(12)` for that particular cell.

For an example, see [TableTest.java](http://itextpdf.org/documents/TableTest.java) and the [resulting PDF](http://itextpdf.org/documents/table.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this is what you are looking for http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=92

Comment: It's a bit like this :  www.dropbox.com/s/txw78c84a3u0b4y/Untitled.png

Comment: I am not able to access the above link in my office networks...its blocked out. :-(